# in iphone apps,,about web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one,

in iphone apps we can use SOAP protocal for accessing web service, but we should pass data in xml format,,is there any protocol which can be used on iphone in which data should not be passed in the form of xml,,,,,thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about ASI? Check this out: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Using this wrapper you can send your post data in `NSDictionary`. There are plenty of other useful wraps.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as 'answered' if it has solved your problem. Put a check mark under gray number with up and down arrows left to the answer text.